# Google docs api error- while trying to update a files title the outcome is a file with my request body params written in it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-drive-api

the code is supposed to make a copy of a document and then change its title, instead it created a document and then change the entire body of the document to the body fields i sent in the request instead of updating the title.

```
function createFilewithtemplate(tag,document_id){
var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
var fileName= "Wib Issues Report - "+tag +' '+ getDateString()
console.log(accessToken)
fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/'+document_id+'/copy',{
  method: "POST",
  headers: new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ accessToken}),
}).then( (res) => {
  return res.json();
  }).then( function(val) {
    fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/'+val.id,{
      method: "PUT",
      headers: new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ accessToken}),
      body: JSON.stringify('title' : 'new file')
    })
  console.log(val);
  console.log(val.id);
  window.open("https://docs.google.com/document/d/" + val.id + "/edit");
});
```

[document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wb2og.png)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `instead it created a document and then change the entire body of the document to the body fields i sent in the request instead of updating the title.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: i am trying to create a copy of a document and then change the new documents name, but when i execute this request it doesnt change the file name, instead it changes its entire body to the fields i sent in the request. you can see the result in the picture i uploaded

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to copy a Google Document and want to rename the copied Document.

In this case, when your showing script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
var fileName= "Wib Issues Report - "+tag +' '+ getDateString();
fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/'+document_id+'/copy',{
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Bearer "+ accessToken,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({name: fileName})
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => {
  console.log(res);
  console.log(res.id);
  window.open("https://docs.google.com/document/d/" + res.id + "/edit");
});
```

- In this modification, the Document is copied and renamed using the method of "Files: copy" in Drive API.

#### Reference:

- [Files: copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy)

Comment: thank, that worked i was missing content type header